# PHP load <option> data into <textarea>

Tags: php

```
<select name="template" id="template">
        <option value="none">Don't use template</option>
        <option value="RWT">Report Abuse</option>
        <option value="renew">Resend Email Codes</option>
    </select><br/>
    <textarea name="body" rows="10" id="content" value="<?php echo $body;?>"ondblclick="select_all('content');" cols="40"></textarea><br/>
```

....

```
else if ($template == "renew") {
        $body = "Dear $username,<br/></br/>";
        $body .= "Here is your requested activation code: $activationID <br/><br/>";
        $body .= "Thank you.<br/>";
    }
```

When I select the option "renew" it doesn't load the data into my textarea.  How can I load option data inside the textarea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to go inside the `textarea` tag:

```
<textarea name="body" rows="10" id="content" ondblclick="select_all('content');" cols="40">
  <?php echo $body;?>
</textarea>
```

**Update**: as tacone mention in the comments, `echo htmlspecialchars($body)` would be better because it's the right way to do things -- in this specific case there will be no difference, but other times unless you do it your application will be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: echo htmlentities($body) would be better.

Comment: @tacone: `htmlspecialchars($body)` would be even better :)

Comment: or maybe filter_var(). Let's let the XSS-prevention flamewar begin :-)

Comment: When I do this it requires me to reload the page.  Is there a way I can do this dynamically?

Comment: @Kyle: you 'd have to use AJAX for that. Search for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the value of a textarea - you simply insert the required content within a pair of textarea elements. For example:

```
<textarea name="body" id="content" ondblclick="select_all('content');" rows="10" cols="40">
<?php echo $body; ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: This sort of works now but I have to reload the page in order for it to display inside the textarea.  How can I make the page reload when I select an option so it loads into the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the template and body variables back to your page for debugging. What are their values?